# reading tables from xlsx sheet and writing datafarame per table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet that contains tables with different sizes (different column numbers and rows).
[Worksheet with tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeNir.png)

I have written the code below to take the tables and save them as separate dataframe.
It seems to work but returns random table numbers/IDs (it does not start from 1 - i.e., table1)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\zz\Desktop\Analyticaldata.xlsx') # Set the filepath + filename

dfa=df.active()
# select the sheet where tables are located
dff = df["Sheet1"]

# check what tables that exist in the worksheet
print({key : value for key, value in dff.tables.items()})

mapping = {}

# loop through all the tables and add to a dictionary
for entry, data_boundary in dff.tables.items():
    # parse the data within the ref boundary
    data = dff[data_boundary]
    
    ### extract the data ###
    # the inner list comprehension gets the values for each cell in the table
    content = [[cell.value for cell in ent] 
               for ent in data]
    
    header = content[0]
    
    #the contents ... excluding the header
    rest = content[1:]
    
    #create dataframe with the column names
    #and pair table name with dataframe
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(rest, columns = header)
    mapping[entry] = df1

#  print(mapping)
# Extract all the tables to individually dataframes from the dictionary
Table4, Table5, Table6, Table7, Table3, Table8, Table9, Table10 = mapping.values()

# Print each dataframe
print(Table4)
print(Table5)
# etc
```

Comment: No, by random I meant I do not get the table numbers starting from 1 instead table ID/# starts from 4. I'd like to understand why table ID/# does not start from 1? (so I do not get random numbers, but I expeted to get table ID starting from 1 i.e., table1)

Comment: Seems you don't have a table with the name 'table1' in the sheet. If you are able, open the workbook in Excel and check the names of the tables.

Comment: tables do not have names the table ID/#s are being generated through the code...

Comment: OK, not sure what that means. What does the line **print({key : value for key, value in dff.tables.items()})** display?